# Hovering Effect in Bootstrap

Tags: html, hover

I want to add the close button on hovering . So I added the following code ->

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.to-hover:hover + .hide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="to-hover">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
      <div>
        <h6 class="my-0">Uploaded File</h6>
        <small class="text-muted">description.txt</small>
      </div>
      <span class="text-muted">3584 words</span>
      <div class="hide">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
     </li>
</div>
```

But When I am hovering over it , I am not getting the close icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put `+` sign here: `.to-hover:hover + .hide`.

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.to-hover:hover .hide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="to-hover">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
      <div>
        <h6 class="my-0">Uploaded File</h6>
        <small class="text-muted">description.txt</small>
      </div>
      <span class="text-muted">3584 words</span>
      <div class="hide">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
     </li>
</div>
```